# OData V4 client pass pass parent and child as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have an OData V4 controller for "Orders" and inside the orders controller I have added a method called "SaveWithChild" that is a HttpPost with parameter of type ODataActionParameters.
In the WebApiConfig I have added an ActionConfiguration for the "SaveWithChild" on the "Orders" entity with a parameter type of "Order".

Now let's assume the "Order" model has a property called "UpdateUser" and also has a child property called "OrderLine" and the OrderLine has a property called "UpdateUser".

Like the following:

```cs
class Order
{
    public string UpdateUser { get; set; }
    public OrderLine OrderLine { get; set; }
}

class OrderLine
{
    public string UpdateUser { get; set; }
}
```

Now on the client side I would like to be able to update the "UpdateUser" field for both the parent "Order" and the child "OrderLine" by calling the "SaveWithChild" method on the controller.

```cs
var context = new Container("URI");
var order = (from o in context.Orders.Expand("OrderLine") where o.ID = 1 select o).FirstOrDefault();
order.UpdateUser = "test";
order.OrderLine.UpdateUser = "test";
context.Orders.SaveWithChild(order);
```

When I run Fiddler I can see that the "OrderLine" object is not being passed with the Order object in the JSON http post.

I can serialize the object into a string, pass it as a string to the controller, and then deserialize it inside the control.
That does work but I am hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:
            DataServiceCollection coll = new DataServiceCollection(context.People.Expand("Photo").Where(p => p.UserName == "russellwhyte"));
            coll.First().Photo.Name = "test";
            coll.First().LastName = "test";
            context.SaveChanges();
Let me know if this does not resolve your issue.

Comment: BTW, if you do not want to use client property tracking, you can update in the way like this,
            var ppp = (from o in context.People.Expand("Photo,Trips") where o.UserName == "russellwhyte" select o).FirstOrDefault();
            var myTrip = ppp.Trips.First();

            ppp.LastName = "test111";
            myTrip.Name = "test1111";

            context.UpdateObject(ppp);
            context.UpdateObject(myTrip);

            context.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithSingleChangeset);

Comment: The answer you have above worked great except it basically calls 2 separate controllers so there seems to be no way to roll them together in a transaction like I can if it only called on controller / method. Your second option of "BatchWithSingleChangeset" looks very promising for transactions except it does not work with the default implementation of "PATCH" which is what is called from the OData .net client code when calling context.SaveChanges...

Comment: Actually your "BatchWithSingleChangeset" does work in a sample project but does not work in my project. I will post that as a new question.